# How to get object id from UIButton?

Tags: cocoa-touch

How to get object id from UIButton ?
I want to know which uibutton is pressed currently when i don't save the pointer to uibutton.

Comment: What do you mean by "object ID" ?

Comment: I fine the answer: use the uibutton.tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not alot to your question so it's hard to understand what you're asking... But, I'll hazard a guess by making the assumption that you're asking for how to get access to a UIButton from within your code? If so, then I'd need to also assume you'd added this button via Interface Builder in which case you simply need to add an `IBOutlet` pre-processor directive for each button object in your view controller (or view's) interface as such:

```
@interface MyView : UIViewController {
     UIButton *myButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

// Button's action which you probably already figured out
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

Then you'll need to make the connections in Interface Builder. Drag FROM the *object that needs to know* TO *the object it needs to know about*. So you'd control-drag from the File's Owner to the UIButton to connect the IBOutlet...and then control-drag from the UIButton back to the File's Owner to connect the IBAction.